# Keep float number in range

Tags: c, if-statement, range

When a public function accepts a float value, and this value is to be kept within a specific range, I usually do:

```
void setParameter(float p)
{
  if (p < 0) p = 0;
  if (p > 1.f) p = 1.f;
  // ...do something with 'p'
}
```

Is there a better, faster, more elegant way to keep a float value in range?

Comment: Many libraries offer a function usually named `clamp` that does this.  It could be called like `p = clamp(p, 0.0f, 1.0f);` but internally, it will probably do the same.  If you need this often, you can write your own `clamp` function.

Comment: I'm partial to `fmax(0, fmin(1.0, p))` although it has different behaviour if p is NaN (more usable with C generics and tgmath.h)

Comment: @rici  Is the "different behavior" in that `fmin(1.0, NaN)` --> `1.0` whereas `if (NaN > 1.f)` is false, leaving `p` as NaN?